# Nginx shows unknown headers

Tags: http, nginx, header, spdy

I have an nginx server which is acting as a reverse proxy.
When I'm dumping the response headers I get the following:

```
---output omitted---
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< : : 
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
---output omitted---
```

The header **: :** is causing some problems and I want to remove it via nginx config.
Is it possible to strip this header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using More Headers module on nginx and adding a directive to strip the headers that I need:

`more_clear_headers ':*';`